# capture the value of the current (not previous) selected radio button with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, radio-button

I want to be able to get the value *that I just selected* when capturing the click of a radio button. The small snippet of code below returns the previous value, however if I click 'Male' then I want to capture it and then do something else with the `gender` var.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $('input[name=gender]').click(function() {
          var gender = $('input[name=gender]:checked').val(); 
     });

});

<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />Male 
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />Female
```

This may appear like a minor question, and likely is, but I may be missing the wood from the trees because it is late in the day.

Comment: `$(this)` not working for you? also, your code works perfectly fine.

Comment: [Your code works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/9u2jr/). Your error must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(this).val()`, It will give you the current radio button being clicked. Your code is also working fine but you are using need less selector. Check demo of your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vMpn9/1/)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vMpn9/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $('input[name=gender]').click(function() {
          var gender = $(this).val(); 
     });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, I **knew** it was a n00b question. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

try change event, this is better solution then click

http://jsbin.com/arohuk/1/edit